# Add [css-hacks] as a tag synonym of [css-hack]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

Could you add [css-hacks](/questions/tagged/css-hacks) as a synonym of [css-hack](/questions/tagged/css-hack)?

Comment: @rene then why was it migrated here from SO meta?